# About the coreAnimation delegate setting?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

How to fix the question for the coreAnimation delegate setting?

Have a look at this

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `CAAnimationDelegate` for your class. Like this

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController < CAAnimationDelegate >
```

Comment: thank you, i think this question maybe content to the CAAnimationDelegate`s property. CAAnimationDelegate